# SQLite Auto increment Integer Primary Key

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment

I know this question has been asked countless times, but I can't get this working for some reason. I am trying to make a very basic user account table in sqlite with the following schema.

```
CREATE TABLE Account (
        User_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        First_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        Last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        Usage_plan INT NOT NULL
);
```

From what I have read it looks like a column that is marked as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY should automatically auto increment.

See here: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
  a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  b INTEGER
);
With this table, the statement

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(NULL,123);
is logically equivalent to saying:

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES((SELECT max(a) FROM t1)+1,123);
```

With this being said I would expect the following statement to work.

```
            String sql = "INSERT INTO Account VALUES (NULL, '" + password + "', '" + firstName + "', '" + lastName + "', " + "1);";
            System.out.println(sql);
            try {
                    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error adding " + firstName + " to netflix users.");
            }
```

but it doesn't. I am getting an error when I run my program that Account.User_id is failing the not null NULL constaint. I have tried many variations of this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Show the actual error message.

Comment: Query "INSERT INTO Account VALUES (NULL, 'pass123', 'abc', 'xyz', 1);" is working. What issue you are facing?